# Difference between geckodriver and marionette

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, firefox-marionette

I don't fully understand the difference between [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver) and [marionette](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette).

- Can anyone clarify the difference between them?

For example, when I use Selenium WebDriver to control a Firefox browser, I need a geckodriver binary to listen the [WebDriver protocol](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html) from Selenium.

- Is Marionette the Firefox extension that actually drives Firefox?

Comment: Did you read the pages you linked? It states pretty clearly what they are.

Comment: I did, and obviously it is not clear for me (for that reason I am asking)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Selenium uses W3C Webdriver protocol to send requests to Geckodriver, which translates them and uses Marionette protocol to send them to Firefox

Selenium<--(W3C Webdriver)-->Geckodriver<---(Marionette)--->Firefox