# Selenium java does not open the firefox web page

Tags: java, selenium, url, firefox, hyperlink

this is my code

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    searchBox.sendKeys("Packt Publishing");
    searchBox.submit();
```

these are my imports:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
```

(i don't know why here it puts them in the same line)

What it does is that it opens a new firefox page with an empty tab ... what's wrong? 
I looked for other people in this site with the same problem and I did not find an answer.

Comment: Selenium-Gecko-Mozilla versions please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While you work with `Selenium` 3.4.0 and `geckodriver` v0.17.0 and `Mozilla Firefox` 53.0, you have to download and save `geckodriver` in your system and provide the absolute path of the `geckodriver` in your code. You can consider to use the following code block to initiate  Google Search by calling `submit()` method:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://google.com");
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Packt Publishing");
    // CASE C : Submitting the Search String through submit()
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Google Search']")).submit();
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: I don't think so even if I put only this code
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
it does not work

Comment: Change `driver.get("google.com");` to `driver.get("https://google.com");`. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry it does not work. I did everything you told me .

Comment: and anyways this code driver.get("google.com"); was an example I did not write exaclty that,.

Comment: See this discussion thread [Why Firefox requires GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43660195/why-firefox-requires-geckodriver/43661697#43661697). If the error still persists, copy your exact code and error stack trace along with  
Selenium-Gecko-Mozilla versions. Thanks