# Gecko Driver gives error cannot run binary file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am getting the error "cannot execute binary file"

Used gecko driver 19.0, selenium 3.6, Firefox 56 
Here is my program and output:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Firefox requires GeckoDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43660195/why-firefox-requires-geckodriver)

Comment: Please don't post error messages and code as images. They are text and should be posted as text.

Answer (score 1):

You are directly passing geckodriver-v0.19.0-macos.tar.gz.

It's not a real file while it's a zip file which you need to extract the geckodriver first and then pass that file in code.

Just double-click on gz file and extract the file or use the command line as below:

```
gunzip -c geckodriver-v0.19.0-macos.tar.gz | tar xopf -
```