# Getting Selenium-WebDriver Example to work

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium

I am completely new to Selenium, and just want to install & run the example to begin with, as described here: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp
I have installed the Java SE 9.0.1 JDK, Eclipse IDE for Java Developers and Apache Maven.
Next I set up a pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>MySel20Proj</groupId>
        <artifactId>MySel20Proj</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</project>
```

Then I did mvn clean install

Then I imported the Maven project into Eclipse.

I also installed the m2eclipse plugin.

I called the project MySel20Proj.

Here, I created a class: Selenium2Example.java

Here, i pasted the code from the manual:

```
package org.openqa.selenium.example;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Selenium2Example {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        // Alternatively the same thing can be done like this
        // driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        // Google's search is rendered dynamically with JavaScript.
        // Wait for the page to load, timeout after 10 seconds
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("cheese!");
            }
        });

        // Should see: "cheese! - Google Search"
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        //Close the browser
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

The instructions seem to stop here. What do I do next? How do I run it?

**Update 11/12/2017**

I am now making some progress with this. The project is finally running, although it is not yet performing the test.

This is my latest POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
      </properties>         
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MySel20Proj</groupId>
    <artifactId>MySel20Proj</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
     <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <includes>
                <include>Selenium2Example.java</include>
              </includes>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
</project>
```

This is the java code:

```
//package org.openqa.selenium.example;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Selenium2Example {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", 
"C:\\Users\\sstaple\\Downloads\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        // Alternatively the same thing can be done like this
        // driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the 
element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        // Google's search is rendered dynamically with JavaScript.
        // Wait for the page to load, timeout after 10 seconds
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>
() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("cheese!");
            }
        });

        // Should see: "cheese! - Google Search"
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        //Close the browser
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

This was the result of running mvn install in the Command Prompt:

```
> C:\Users\sstaple\eclipse-workspace\MySel20Proj>mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MySel20Proj 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ MySel20Proj ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ MySel20Proj ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ MySel20Proj ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ MySel20Proj ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\sstaple\eclipse-workspace\MySel20Proj\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test (default-test) @ MySel20Proj ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running Selenium2Example
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 s - in Selenium2Example
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ MySel20Proj ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\sstaple\eclipse-workspace\MySel20Proj\target\MySel20Proj-1.0.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ MySel20Proj ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\sstaple\eclipse-workspace\MySel20Proj\target\MySel20Proj-1.0.jar to C:\Users\sstaple\.m2\repository\MySel20Proj\MySel20Proj\1.0\MySel20Proj-1.0.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\sstaple\eclipse-workspace\MySel20Proj\pom.xml to C:\Users\sstaple\.m2\repository\MySel20Proj\MySel20Proj\1.0\MySel20Proj-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.089 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-11T11:31:42Z
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/55M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Update 2 - 11/12/2017**

Had to add a bunch of Depencies to the pom file to get it to compile clean:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>21.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna-platform -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
        <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.cssparser/cssparser -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.cssparser</groupId>
        <artifactId>cssparser</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/htmlunit-core-js -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit-core-js</artifactId>
        <version>2.23</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/htmlunit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.23</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/neko-htmlunit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>neko-htmlunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.23</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-io</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.15.v20160210</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.15.v20160210</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty.websocket/websocket-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>websocket-api</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.15.v20160210</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty.websocket/websocket-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>websocket-client</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.15.v20160210</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty.websocket/websocket-common -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>websocket-common</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.15.v20160210</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/htmlunit-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.23</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/jetty-repacked -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-repacked</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.13.v20160825</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-edge-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-edge-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-firefox-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-ie-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-opera-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-opera-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-safari-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-safari-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Still does nothing at all:

```
> C:\Users\sstaple\eclipse-workspace\MySel20Proj>mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MySel20Proj 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/21.0/guava-21.0.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/21.0/guava-21.0.jar (2.5 MB at 2.6 MB/s)
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ MySel20Proj ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ MySel20Proj ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ MySel20Proj ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ MySel20Proj ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\sstaple\eclipse-workspace\MySel20Proj\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test (default-test) @ MySel20Proj ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running Selenium2Example
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.008 s - in Selenium2Example
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ MySel20Proj ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\sstaple\eclipse-workspace\MySel20Proj\target\MySel20Proj-1.0.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ MySel20Proj ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\sstaple\eclipse-workspace\MySel20Proj\target\MySel20Proj-1.0.jar to C:\Users\sstaple\.m2\repository\MySel20Proj\MySel20Proj\1.0\MySel20Proj-1.0.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\sstaple\eclipse-workspace\MySel20Proj\pom.xml to C:\Users\sstaple\.m2\repository\MySel20Proj\MySel20Proj\1.0\MySel20Proj-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.032 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-11T13:56:34Z
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/63M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Firefox requires GeckoDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43660195/why-firefox-requires-geckodriver)

Comment: It is not a duplication of anything. I am not trying to use GeckoDriver.

Comment: As per your Question to work with **`org.seleniumhq.selenium selenium-server 3.0.1`** you mandatory need to use `GeckoDriver`.

Comment: I do not see how that even relates to my question.

Comment: My question is not about GeckoDriver or Firefox!!!

Comment: The error I get, when I run it, is 'selection does not contain a main type'. This is baffling, as the class clearly DOES have a main type.

Comment: Have a look at this-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225177/error-selection-does-not-contain-a-main-type

Answer (score 2):

As per the code block you have shared everything looks fine. But again as you mentioned *org.seleniumhq.selenium selenium-server 3.0.1* you have to mandatory download *geckodriver* binary from this [repository](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and place it in your system. Next in your code block you need to mention as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

---

### Execution Steps :

1. Save the `Selenium2Example.java` and the `pom.xml` file
2. In the *Package Explorer*, right click on `pom.xml`, select *Run As* and select *Maven clean*
3. In the *Package Explorer*, right click on `pom.xml`, select *Run As* and select *Maven install*.
4. In the *Package Explorer*, right click on *pom.xml*, select *Run As* and select *Maven test*.

---

### Update 1

As you are seeing the error as `selection does not contain a main type`, ensure that your `.java` file is within `\ProjectSpace\src\test\java\`.

---

### Update 2

As you still see `No sources to compile`, as a last resort, *Clean* all of your *Projects* within your *IDE*, *Close* the *IDE*, *Delete* the `~\.m2` (MAVEN_HOME) sub-directory from the system forcefully. Take a *System Reboot* and execute your *Test*. Additionally from the command line even you can do a `mvn clean`, `mvn install` and `mvn test`.

Comment: Thank you DebanjanB. I have done all that. Nothing at all happened. After Maven Test, the Console says: No sources to compile. I expected the example to actually work!?!

Comment: As a last resort, `Clean` all of your `Projects` within your `IDE`, `Close` the `IDE`, `Delete` the `m2` (Maven_HOME) folder from the system forcibly. Take a `System Reboot`. try to `Execute` you `Test`. Additionally from the command line even you can do a **`mvn clean`**, **`mvn install`** and **`mvn test`**

Comment: OK. I have moved Selenium2Example.java to the folder eclipse-workspace\MySel20Proj\src\test\java, done mvn clean, mvn install and mvn test.  Says build success, but nothing happened. I am thinking it should load a browser & go to Google! I do not see a Maven_HOME folder?

Comment: Maven by default picks up class files with *Test* in the name, either change name or include the class in the pom. Details refer this - http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html. Plus maven will pick up test methods which are annotated with the Test annotation from junit or testng. It will not run main methods. https://www.testwithspring.com/lesson/running-unit-tests-with-maven/

Comment: Thank you Grasshopper. You would think whoever composed the Example on the SeleniumHQ website would have written an example that worked. A bit useless if Maven does not pick up Main methods, for example. The instructions leave a lot to be desired - and are incomplete.

Comment: I am not sure how @Grasshopper concludes that. However I still continue to run some of my `Tests` from a `Maven Project` as a `Java Project` without involving the `TestNG`. Can we have some more insights please?

Comment: Getting this example to work is just one problem after another! Now getting this error: at org.apache.bcel.verifier.exc.AssertionViolatedException.main(AssertionViolatedException.java:102). the jar file M2_REPO\xalan\xalan\2.7.2\xalan-2.7.2.jar has no source attachment.

Comment: Issue with `M2_REPO`, Clean all of your Projects within your IDE, Close the IDE, Delete the m2 (MAVEN_HOME) folder from the system forcibly. Take a System Reboot. Try to Execute you Test. Additionally from the command line even you can do a mvn clean, mvn install and mvn test. Btw how does the `xalan-2.7.2.jar` comes into picture?

Comment: Thanks DebanjanB. I cannot see any Maven_HOME folder. It is not shown as a Path Variable in the Projects Properties. I have no idea why it wanted the xalan-2.7.2.jar. but it appears to be a Maven resource. (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xalan/xalan/2.7.2). None of this information is included on the SeleniumHQ website.

Comment: See on Windows machine `C:\Users\<your_user_name>\.m2` is my **MAVEN_HOME** or **M2_REPO**. Delete this folder and take a fresh `maven clean & install`. Remove unwanted Maven Dependencies from your **`pom.xml`** as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160923/discussion-between-steve-staple-and-debanjanb).

Comment: Use updated `Selenium v3.8.1` Maven Dependency. As per your code you don't need a `xalan-2.7.2.jar`

Comment: Guess maven also runs test methods with the string 'test' in them, though i have always worked with the annotation. Regarding running main method you will need to configure another plugin, exec-maven-plugin. Refer to this link - http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/. @SteveStaple The documentation is a lot to be desired and also outdated with latest version, but it is open source and volunteer contributed. Better option would be to refer to millions of selenium tutorials.

Comment: Thank you Grasshopper. Could you recommend a decent tutorial? It is pretty difficult trying to learn with this example.

Comment: Thank you DebanjanB. I got further this time. I deleted the folder \.m2. Then I rebooted my laptop. Then I did mvn clean & mvn install. It actually produced this output: [INFO] Running Selenium2Example
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 s - in Selenium2Example. It is not what I was expecting, but progress is being made.

Comment: Get the entire error stack trace within the question area please.

Comment: Thank you DebanjanB. I have updated the original question.

Comment: Your `pom.xml` is clearly missing the **`maven-compiler-plugin`**. Once you add it you would be through.

Comment: Have had to add a load of depencies to the pom file to get a clean compile. The project now compiles, but still does nothing at all when I run it.

Comment: I do not think it is running my code at all. I put System.out.println("Hello world!"); at the top of the procedure so that I would at least see something. Still nothing.