# java: error reading C:\Users\SP00780555\.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone error executing testcases using Selenium in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, selenium-chromedriver

Im trying to run simple selenium script in IntelliJ. This is the code I used

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\SP00780555\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

But when I'm trying to run it, it's showing this error:

```
java: error reading C:\Users\SP00780555\.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.1.3\error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar; zip file is empty
```

Comment: Try clearing Maven local repo:  `C:\Users\SP00780555\.m2\` Seems it is corrupted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
java: error reading C:\Users\SP00780555\.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.1.3\error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar; zip file is empty
```

...implies that your program is unable to read the local ***Maven*** repository i.e. some of the contents from **`.m2`** directory as the repository possibly got corrupted.

---

### Solution

To address this issue you can adopt any of the following two approaches:

1. *Run*: `Maven clean`, `Maven install` and `Maven test`
2. Delete the `.m2` directory and *Run*: *`mvn clean`*, *`mvn install`* and *`mvn test`* (the libraries within the maven repositories will downloaded afresh)

---

### References

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Getting Selenium-WebDriver Example to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717377/getting-selenium-webdriver-example-to-work/47718057#47718057)