# Unable to launch Firefox browser using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am using Firefox version of 57.0 in my system, and for automation I am using selenium standalone server of 3.0.1 and gecko driver of 0.12.0. The below code is being used for invoking the firefox browser:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",properties.getProperty("GeckoDriverPath"));
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

But during execution after launching the browser it is not being navigated to the desired URL.

Please let me know if I have missed any steps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Firefox requires GeckoDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43660195/why-firefox-requires-geckodriver)

Comment: you are using very outdated versions of selenium and geckodriver

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the latest version geckodriver - https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Comment: I have downloaded the latest version of selenium and geckodriver. Now it had stopped launching the firefox browser and giving me the below error:

**Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities.merge(Lorg/openqa/selenium/Capabilities;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/Capabilities;** 
Firefox browser version: 57.0.2
Selenium server standalone: 3.5.0
Gecko Driver Version: 18.0