# selenium : not start a new session

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I add this line to my code, the connection is not occurring with Mozilla. a browser is opening but it's not redirecting to link.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C://Users//Admi//workspace//Cloud_Optimus//src//Files//geckodriver.exe");
```

Not able to import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.MarionetteDriver.

I am using below versions:

```
Selenium server-standalone - 3.4.0
Firefox: 52
Gecko Driver: 16.0
```

When I use below code it works fine...

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C://Users//Admi//workspace//Cloud_Optimus//src//Files//geckodriver.exe")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between geckodriver and marionette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956380/difference-between-geckodriver-and-marionette)

Comment: Watch this [Question/Discussion/Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43660195/why-firefox-requires-geckodriver/43661697#43661697) for a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver)

> With Selenium 3.0 and later, you shouldn't need to do anything to use
>   Marionette, as it's enabled by default.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C://Users//Admi//workspace//Cloud_Optimus//src//Files//geckodriver.exe");
```

Is the correct way.